# Linearity of the operation of differentiation [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was reading Zorich's book to review some stuff and I came across the following question. Firstly, I am sorry that I am asking this really trivial question (maybe?) but I just want to be sure.

> **Theorem 1.** If the mappings $f_1:E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f_2:E\to \mathbb{R}^n$, defined on an open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, are
> differentiable at a point $x\in E$, then a linear combination of them
> $(\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2):E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is also differentiable
> at that point, and the following equality holds:
> $$(\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2)'(x)=(\lambda_1f'_1+\lambda_2f'_2)(x) \quad \quad \quad (*)$$

The proof of this theorem looks really easy. Actually it shows that $$(\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2)'(x)=\lambda_1f'_1(x)+\lambda_2f'_2(x). \quad \quad \quad (**)$$
However, the RHS in the equaltiy $(*)$ is different and the RHS does not make sense to me. I believe that the correct equality is $(**)$.

Am I right? Or am I missing something?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd interpret it this way: $f$ is given to be differentiable at $x$ so $f'$ is known to exist at $x$, therefore $f': A\to R^n,$ with $A=\{x\}$ makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

These two expressions are equivalent, because it is how we define multiplication and addition of functions.

Given functions $f,g : A \to B$, we define the function $f+g : A \to B$ by

$$(f+g)(x) := f(x)+g(x)$$

For an appropriate scalar $\alpha$, we define the function $\alpha f : A \to B$ by

$$(\alpha f)(x) := \alpha \Big( f(x) \Big) = \alpha f(x)$$

(and of course, similarly, $fg : A \to B$ has $(fg)(x) := f(x)g(x)$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I know this definition very well and I've used it million times but probably I am confused with the notation. Look, $f'(x),g'(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ are linear mappings. Their domain is the set of all $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$. One can define their sum $(\alpha f'(x)+\beta g'(x)):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ as follows: $(\alpha f'(x)+\beta g'(x))[h]:=\alpha f'(x)[h]+\beta g'(x)[h]$. But it does not answering what I am asking for, right? Here $x$ is fixed and $h$ is a variable.

Comment: @ZFR: If you apply this answer to $f'$ and $g'$ viewed as mappings from $E$ to the space of linear mappings from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the right-hand sides of $(*)$ and $(**)$ become equal by definition.

Comment: @HansLundmark, but I think instead of $E$ one needs to take $\{x\}$? Because $f’$ may not be defined on whole $E$. Right?

Comment: @ZFR: Sure. Or the intersection of the sets where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable.

Comment: @HansLundmark, indeed, it was so trivial that it is a bit shameful that I asked such a question :) Let $S\subset E$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable. One can consider the following two functions: 1) $S\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined as $x\mapsto f'(x)$ and 2) $S\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined as $x\mapsto g'(x)$. Fix $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, then one can define $(\alpha f'+\beta g'):S\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined as $x\mapsto \alpha f'(x)+\beta g'(x)$, i.e. $(\alpha f'+\beta g')(x)=\alpha f'(x)+\beta g'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

They both represent the same quantity! Note that if $f$ and $g$ are functions which take values in any group, we *define* the function $f+g$ to be the function sends $x$ to $f(x)+g(x)$. In other words,
$$
(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)
$$
holds by definition of the quantity $(f+g)(x)$.